# infinispan cache server expiration failure

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

I am using infinispan-5.1.6.FINAL as a remote-cache server and hot-rod protocol to access it. but found the  is not working as intended, i.e cached value of a key is not evicted after 1ms as per the config below

```
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:infinispan="urn:infinispan:config:5.1"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd">
    <global >
        <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
    </global>

    <namedCache name="my-cache">
        <expiration lifespan="1" maxIdle="1" reaperEnabled="true" wakeUpInterval="1" />
    </namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

I exploded war (infinispan-5.1.6.FINAL/modules/rest/infinispan-server-rest.war), saved the above config, changed web.xml to use it and deployed in tomcat 6.0.32

I was able to put into the cache and retrieve from it, by this resource

```
http://localhost:8080/infinispan-server-rest/rest/my-cache/1
```

but the entry is not evicted even after 10mins. btw the same config was working in embedded-cache mode.

did I miss something? how can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour of the REST server is to store entries indefinitely, regardless of the cache settings. If you want to use the default expiration settings of the cache, you have to specify `timeToLiveSeconds=0` and `maxIdleTimeSeconds=0`.

This may change in future releases, see https://community.jboss.org/message/796785#796785.

Comment: You are a lifesaver.  I was not finding this anywhere.  By the way, I read the issue.  It may be (or have been) too late in the game to change the REST Server API, but they could have at least updated the docs to state this explicitly.  I was intentionally avoiding sending any optional parameters on the request!